# Conditions for two optimization problems to yield the same solution

Tags: analysis, optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, regression

> **Problem:** Consider the optimization problems
>   $$\min_\beta \|y-X\beta\|^2+\alpha\|\beta\|^2 \tag 1$$
>   and
>   $$\min_\beta \|\beta\|^2 \text{ subject to } \|y-X\beta\|^2 \le c \tag 2$$
>   where $\|x\|$ is the $2$-norm. Fix $\alpha$, and suppose $\beta^*$ is the solution to ($1$), and let  $c=\|y-X\beta^*\|^2$. Is it true that the solution to ($2$) is also $\beta^*$?

**Attempt:** I believe this is true. The argument should be very similar to the one in [Why are additional constraint and penalty term equivalent in ridge regression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335306/why-are-additional-constraint-and-penalty-term-equivalent-in-ridge-regression). However, I was running some numerical experiments and it turns out the two problems have different solutions. Hence my question here: are the two problems really yielding the same solutions? Are there exceptions that I should be careful of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true for $\alpha>0$. Since $\beta^*$ is solution of (1), we have:
$$\|y-X\beta^*\|^2 + \alpha\|\beta^*\|^2 \le \|y-X\beta\|^2 + \alpha\|\beta\|^2.$$
Reordering:
$$\|\beta^*\|^2 \le \frac{1}{\alpha}(\|y-X\beta\|^2 - \|y-X\beta^*\|^2) + \|\beta\|^2.$$
Now, in (2) we take $\beta$ such that $\|y-X\beta\|^2 \le \|y-X\beta^*\|^2$, so we conclude that
$$\|\beta^*\|^2 \le \|\beta\|^2,$$
which implies that $\beta^*$ is a minimum of (2).

Analogously, for $\alpha<0$ you can check that $\beta^*$ solution of (1) is also solution of (2), BUT maximizing instead of minimizing:
$$\alpha(\|\beta^*\|^2 - \|\beta\|^2) \le \|y-X\beta\|^2 - \|y-X\beta^*\|^2 \le 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \|\beta^*\|^2 \ge \|\beta\|^2.$$
Anyhow, note that you cannot assure equivalence, since the problem becomes non-convex for $\alpha<0$.

Comment: I'm not convinced of your final statement. For one thing setting $\alpha<0$ may make this problem non-convex. But I see no reason to believe it would give equivalent solutions if I were "maximizing instead of minimizing". After all, you're not negating the _entire_ objective, just the regularizer.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I did not say it is equivalent ;) Anyway, I have added a note to make clear that solution of (1) would be solution of (2) (maximizing instead of minimizing), but not the other way around.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see it for the non-convex case at all. Fortunately I believe the OP is likely concerning himself with the convex case.

Comment: Please, correct me if I'm wrong, because maybe I'm missing something. For any $\alpha<0$, $\beta^*$ being solution of (1) implies $\|y-X\beta^*\|^2 + \alpha\|\beta^*\|^2 \le \|y-X\beta\|^2 + \alpha\|\beta\|^2$ for all $\beta$. Therefore, $\alpha(\|\beta^*\|^2 - \|\beta\|^2) \le \|y-X\beta\|^2 - \|y-X\beta^*\|^2$ for all $\beta$. Assuming that $\|y-X\beta\|^2 \le \|y-X\beta^*\|^2$, we conclude that $\|\beta^*\|^2 \ge \|\beta\|^2$ for all $\beta$. So $\beta^* = \max_\beta \|\beta\|^2$ subject to $\|y-X\beta\|^2 \le \|y-X\beta^*\|^2$.

Comment: "Assuming that $\|y-X\beta\|^2\leq \|y-X\beta^*\|$" but that's just it, you can't make that assumption. The point of adding a regularizer like $\|beta\|^2$ is that you're willing to trade on the optimal value of error in exchange for other criteria.

Comment: Cannot we assume that from "subject to $\|y−X\beta\|^2 ≤ c$", knowing that $c=\|y−X\beta^*\|^2$ (which is given by OP)?

Comment: Aha, that's the missing piece I wasn't seeing. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @MichaelGrant You are welcome. You made a good observation, though. Non-equivalence needs to be mentioned, in order to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Here from (1)

$$
f(\beta) = y'\cdot y-2\beta'\cdot X'y+\beta'\cdot X'\cdot X\cdot\beta+\alpha \beta'\cdot\beta
$$

so the minimum condition gives

$$
-X'\cdot y+X'\cdot X\beta+\alpha\beta = 0
$$

and then

$$
\beta^* = (I\alpha +X'\cdot X)^{-1}X'\cdot y
$$

and from (2)

$$
L(\beta,\lambda,\epsilon)=\beta'\cdot\beta + \lambda(y'\cdot y-2\beta'\cdot X'y+\beta'\cdot X'\cdot X\cdot\beta-c+\epsilon^2)
$$

the stationary points are

$$
L_{\beta} = 2\beta-2\lambda X'\cdot y + 2\lambda X'\cdot X\cdot\beta = 0
$$

then

$$
(I+\lambda X'\cdot X)\cdot\beta^* = \lambda X'\cdot y
$$

or

$$
\beta^* = (I\frac{1}{\lambda}+X'\cdot X)^{-1}\cdot X'\cdot y
$$

but

$$
\beta'^*\cdot\beta^*-\lambda\beta'^*\cdot X'\cdot y+\lambda \beta'^*\cdot X'\cdot X\cdot\beta^* = 0
$$

and

$$
\lambda = \frac{\beta'\cdot\beta}{y'\cdot y-\beta'\cdot X'\cdot y-c+\epsilon^2}
$$

so the equivalence between (1) and (2) needs

$$
\lambda = \frac{1}{\alpha} = \frac{\beta'^*\cdot\beta^*}{y'\cdot y-\beta'^*\cdot X'\cdot y-c+\epsilon^2}
$$

or

$$
\alpha = \frac{(y-X\cdot \beta^*)'\cdot y-c+\epsilon}{\beta'^*\cdot\beta^*}
$$

which is quite unlikely