# Tikhonov regularized least-squares problem with non-negative constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, regularization, inverse-problems

For a Tikhonov Regularized  Least Squares problem with nonnegative constraints, what are some methods that solve it?

$$\begin{align*} 
\arg \min_{w} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| X w - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\ 
\text{subject to} \quad & w \succeq 0
\end{align*}$$

Are methods solving a Least Squares problem with nonnegative constraints and the solution to a Tikhonov Regularized  Least Squares problem helpful to the above question?

I am searching for some references to address my questions, but haven't found one yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first agree on the problem you are trying to solve. I assume you are looking at:
\begin{align*}
\min_{w}~&f(w):=\frac{1}{2} \Vert y-Xw\Vert +\frac{\lambda}{2}w^tw\\
s.t.~& w\geq 0
\end{align*}
where $y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ \vdots \\y_n\end{pmatrix}$ contains the observations, $X=\begin{pmatrix}
\leftarrow & x_1 & \rightarrow\\
&\vdots&\\
\leftarrow & x_n & \rightarrow
\end{pmatrix}$ the feature vectors and $w=\begin{pmatrix}w_1\\ \vdots \\ w_m \end{pmatrix}$ the weights.

The simplest algorithm you could use to solve the problem is a projected gradient method. Consider the gradient of the objective function at a point $w_k$:
\begin{equation*}
\nabla_w f(w_k)=(X^TX+\lambda I)w_k-X^Ty
\end{equation*} 
and let $\Pi_C$ be the projection onto the set $C:=\{w:~w\geq 0\}$, specifically:
$\Pi_C(w)=\begin{pmatrix}\tilde{w}_1\\ \vdots \\ \tilde{w}_m \end{pmatrix}$, where $\tilde{w}_i=\begin{cases}
w_i &\text{if }w_i\geq 0\\
0 &\text{else}
\end{cases}$.

The projected gradient algorithm works just like the steepest descent algorithm with the addition of a projection step after the gradient step:

- Start with a feasible $w_0$ and let $k:=1$,
- at iteration $k$ let:
  \begin{align*}
  y_k&=w_k -\alpha \nabla_wf(w_k)\\
  w_{k}&=\Pi_C(y_k)\\
  k&=k+1
  \end{align*}
  where $\alpha$ is your step length, found for example using a line search. Repeat this step until you meet your desired stopping criterion.

Look into gradient projection methods to find something more elaborate, but this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, Joe! I appreciate that.